# Is there any post-hoc test for multiple comparisons after conducting the Friedman test by two group using a preference ranking questionnaires?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, post-hoc, friedman-test

I have this dataframe:

```
group1<- matrix(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5)), ncol=4)

group2<- matrix(c(rep(4,5),rep(3,5),rep(2,5),rep(1,5)), ncol=4)
```

I would like to compare these two groups with data of the preference ranking questionnaires. To my knowledge, the comparison of these two groups could be conducting the friedman.test using two matrices.

```
friedman.test(group1,group2)
```

However, I don’t know any post-hoc test for multiple comparisons using the two matrices in the friedman.test. I know there are some like the posthoc.friedman.conover.test or posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test, that seem to use only one matrix, that is, these tests analize the effect in one matrix but not between both matrices.

If there is no post-hoc test, could you tell me another test to compare the two groups using matrices (or dataframes) and their multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [posthoc.friedman.conover.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PMCMR/versions/4.3/topics/posthoc.friedman.conover.test) and here is the sample code

```
posthoc.friedman.conover.test(y=y, p.adjust="none")
```

or [Nemenyi-Test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PMCMR/versions/4.3/topics/posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test)

```
posthoc.friedman.nemenyi.test(y)
```

y = matrix

Comment: Thanks Heinz, I know about your solution. However, I don´t know any post-hoc after coducting two matrices in the Frienman test. For only one matrix in the test, there are several post-hoc tests as you mention.

Comment: we can merge it to single dataframe, then do that post test
`data <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("Group1", "Group2"), each = xxx),
                   Preference = c(group1, group2))`